# Oriented but not Reversible manifolds?

Tags: differential-topology, surgery-theory

In Hirsch's Differential Topology, he defines a smooth manifold $M$ to be **reversable** if it is orientable and admits an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism. I feel confused since I believe that any orientable manifold should admit one such diffeomorphisms. Are there any counter-examples for this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/orientation-reversing-diffeomorphism

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you.